# Cannot display correct legend information from an array using plotly JS

Tags: plotly.js

I am trying to create a scatter plot using ploty JS on an HTML div element. The plot looks fine, except that I'm unable to display correct legend information on the plot.
The reproducible example can be found in this [codepen link](https://codepen.io/wasimaftab/pen/LYzbvmv). However, I am pasting below the JS code:

```
var fc = [2, 3, 0.5, 1];
var p_mod = [0.05, 0.04, 0.08, 0.09];
var gene = ["gene1", "gene2", "gene3", "gene4"]
var NegLogPvalMod = p_mod.map(x => -Math.log10(x));
var col = ["#BF382A", "#BF382A","#0C4B8E", "#0C4B8E"];
var leg = ["Sig", "Sig", "Not-sig", "Not-sig"];
/* create custom hover text */
    var my_text = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < fc.length; i++) {
        my_text.push('Fold Change: ' + fc[i] + '<br>' +
            '-log 10[p-value]: ' + NegLogPvalMod[i] + '<br>' +
            'Gene: ' + gene[i]);
    }

var trace = {
    x: fc,
    y: NegLogPvalMod,
   text: my_text,
    mode: "markers",
    marker: {
            color: col,
            size: 6,
            line: {
                color: "black",
                width: 0.25
            }
        },
    type: "scatter",
  hovertemplate: '%{text}<extra></extra>',
    hoverinfo: 'skip',
    name: leg
};

var data = [trace];

var layout = {
    hovermode: 'closest',
    title: 'scatter plot',
    showlegend: true,
         xaxis: {
            title: "<b>log2 fold change</b>"
        },
        yaxis: {
            title: "<b>-log10 p-value</b>"
        }
};

Plotly.newPlot(document.getElementById("myDiv"), data, layout, {responsive: true});
```

Presently, the `trace 0` is the only legend that is being displayed (see image below)

[image]

However, I would like `Sig` & `Not-sig` to appear as legends with blue and red dots (at the left of the texts) respectively. I could not find a similar example in the plolty JS documentation. Therefore, any suggestions to solve this issue will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get the job done and updated the Codepen link. However, I feel my solution is not elegant. If anyone has a better solution that uses legend from a single array then I will appreciate that.